# Why doesn't PHPDoc differentiate between a float and a double?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

From http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#primitives

it seems like PHPDoc only recognizes type `float`.

Seeing how PHP is written in C/C++, I wonder why it does not offer `double` as a type.

Comment: double is the type used internally for floats.... try doing gettype() on a float value (`$x = 1.2; echo gettype($x);`).... but the PHP docs talk consistently about float

Comment: PHPdoc only recognises floats because that is the type that PHP has. Why PHP supports that isn't a practical problem, so isn't really suitable for stackoverflow. It's likely to attract opinions rather than answers (unless someone can find a decades old design document that explains the implementation decisions made back in the day).

Comment: For the same reason that it doesn't offer Enum or pointers.

Comment: my main concern I suppose was that the values are treated as double and not as float.  Glad that see that it is abstracted as double

Comment: @Dennis PHP doesn't make a guarantee as to the size of a float. It's platform dependent. If you have hard-requirements for the precision of the numbers, use http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Answer (score 1):

The language PHP implementations are written in does not affect what PHP recognizes (C doesn't have the concept of strings as PHP understands them, but PHP has them).

The [floating point type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) is called `float` in PHP, so it makes sense for tools built for php only recognize that type. The internal/C representation of a PHP floating point is abstracted to the PHP code. A point of interest is that a float in PHP is typically stored in a C double.